# EF 7 Core MySQL entity type

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am currently trying to display a table with multiple CVE values in mysql.
However, I get the following error (Could not save changes. Please configure your entity type accordingly.)
However, I do not have any triggers defined in the database, so I am wondering if there is an error somewhere else.

My database model looks like this:

```
 public class CVEDBModel
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string sourceIdentifier { get; set; }
    public DateTime published { get; set; }
    public DateTime lastModified { get; set; }
    public string vulnStatus { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Description> Description { get; set; }

    public string source { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CvssData> CvssData { get; set; }

    public string baseSeverity { get; set; }
    public double exploitabilityScore { get; set; }
    public double impactScore { get; set; }
    public bool acInsufInfo { get; set; }
    public bool obtainAllPrivilege { get; set; }
    public bool obtainUserPrivilege { get; set; }

    public bool obtainOtherPrivilege { get; set; }
    public bool userInteractionRequired { get; set; }
    public string weaknessesSource { get; set; }

    public bool vulnerable { get; set; }

    public string criteria { get; set; }
    public string matchCriteriaId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<References> References { get; set; }
}
public class CvssData 
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public double version { get; set; }
    public string vectorString { get; set; }
    public string accessVector { get; set; }
    public string accessComplexity { get; set; }
    public string authentication { get; set; }
    public string confidentialityImpact { get; set; }
    public string integrityImpact { get; set; }
    public string availabilityImpact { get; set; }
    public double baseScore { get; set; }

    public virtual CVEDBModel CVEDBModel { get; set; }
}
public class Description
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string lang { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }

    public virtual CVEDBModel CVEDBModel { get; set; }
}

public class References
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string source { get; set; }
    public virtual CVEDBModel CVEDBModel { get; set; }
}
```

My Context Class Looks like this

```
public class CVEContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<CVEDBModel> CVEDBModel { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CvssData> CvssData { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Description> Description { get; set; }
    public DbSet<References> References { get; set; }
   

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseMySQL("server=localhost;database=cve;user=root;password=testr");
    }

    protected override void ConfigureConventions(ModelConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder)
    {
        configurationBuilder.Conventions.Add(_ => new BlankTriggerAddingConvention());
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<CVEDBModel>().ToTable(tb => tb.HasTrigger("SomeTrigger"));

        modelBuilder.Entity<CVEDBModel>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.id);
            entity.Property(e => e.baseSeverity).IsRequired();
            entity.Property(e => e.obtainUserPrivilege).IsRequired();
            entity.Property(e => e.obtainOtherPrivilege).IsRequired();
            entity.Property(e => e.obtainAllPrivilege).IsRequired();
            entity.Property(e => e.weaknessesSource).IsRequired();
            entity.Property(e => e.acInsufInfo).IsRequired();
            entity.Property(e => e.vulnerable).IsRequired();
            entity.Property(e => e.baseSeverity).IsRequired();
            entity.Property(e => e.criteria).IsRequired();
            entity.Property(e => e.exploitabilityScore).IsRequired();
            entity.Property(e => e.impactScore).IsRequired();
            entity.Property(e => e.lastModified).IsRequired();
            entity.Property(e => e.matchCriteriaId).IsRequired();
            entity.Property(e => e.sourceIdentifier).IsRequired();
            entity.Property(e => e.published).IsRequired();
            entity.Property(e => e.vulnStatus).IsRequired();
            entity.Property(e => e.published).IsRequired();
            entity.Property(e => e.source).IsRequired();
            entity.Property(e => e.userInteractionRequired).IsRequired();
            
        });


        modelBuilder.Entity<CvssData>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.id);
            entity.Property(e => e.version).IsRequired();
            entity.Property(e => e.vectorString).IsRequired();
            entity.Property(e => e.accessVector).IsRequired();
            entity.Property(e => e.accessComplexity).IsRequired();
            entity.Property(e => e.authentication).IsRequired();
            entity.Property(e => e.confidentialityImpact).IsRequired();
            entity.Property(e => e.integrityImpact).IsRequired();
            entity.Property(e => e.availabilityImpact).IsRequired();
            entity.Property(e => e.baseScore).IsRequired();
            

        });


        modelBuilder.Entity<Description>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.id);
            entity.Property(e => e.lang).IsRequired();
            entity.Property(e => e.value).IsRequired();
            


        });
   

        modelBuilder.Entity<References>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.id);
            entity.Property(e => e.url).IsRequired();
            entity.Property(e => e.source).IsRequired();
            entity.HasOne(d => d.CVEDBModel).WithMany(p => p.References);

        });

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        
    }
}
public class BlankTriggerAddingConvention : IModelFinalizingConvention
{
    public virtual void ProcessModelFinalizing(
        IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder,
        IConventionContext<IConventionModelBuilder> context)
    {
        foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Metadata.GetEntityTypes())
        {
            var table = StoreObjectIdentifier.Create(entityType, StoreObjectType.Table);
            if (table != null
                && entityType.GetDeclaredTriggers().All(t => t.GetDatabaseName(table.Value) == null))
            {
                entityType.Builder.HasTrigger(table.Value.Name + "_Trigger");
            }

            foreach (var fragment in entityType.GetMappingFragments(StoreObjectType.Table))
            {
                if (entityType.GetDeclaredTriggers().All(t => t.GetDatabaseName(fragment.StoreObject) == null))
                {
                    entityType.Builder.HasTrigger(fragment.StoreObject.Name + "_Trigger");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At the end, im trying to create the tables and the entry in the following way.
The tables are created but no entries are made.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        InsertData();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Oh no! An exception occurred trying to do the math.\n - Details: " + e.Message);
    }
}
private static void InsertData()
{
    using (var context = new CVEContext())
    {
        // Creates the database if not exists
        context.Database.EnsureCreated();


        // Adds a publisher
        var cve = new CVEDBModel
        {
            id = "CVE-1999-0095",
            sourceIdentifier = "cve@mitre.org",
            published = DateTime.Parse("1988-10-01T04:00:00.000"),
            lastModified = DateTime.Parse("2019-06-11T20:29:00.263"),
            source = "nvd@nist.gov",
            baseSeverity = "HIGH",
            exploitabilityScore = 10.0,
            impactScore = 10.0,
            acInsufInfo = false,
            obtainAllPrivilege = true,
            obtainUserPrivilege = false,
            obtainOtherPrivilege = false,
            userInteractionRequired = false,
            weaknessesSource = "nvd@nist.gov",
            vulnerable = true,
            criteria = "cpe:2.3:a:eric_allman:sendmail:5.58:*:*:*",
            matchCriteriaId = "1D07F493-9C8D-44A4-8652-F28B46CBA27C"
        };
        context.CVEDBModel.Add(cve);

        var description = new CVEFillerService.Description
        {
            lang = "en",
            value = "The debug command in Sendmail is enabled, allowing attackers to execute commands as root.",
            CVEDBModel = cve
        };
        context.Description.Add(description);
        var cvssData = new CVEFillerService.CvssData
        {
            version = 2.0,
            vectorString = "edfrde",
            accessVector = "NETWORK",
            accessComplexity = "LOW",
            authentication = "none",
            confidentialityImpact = "COMPLETE",
            integrityImpact = "COMPLETE",
            availabilityImpact = "COMPLETE",
            baseScore = 10.0,
            CVEDBModel = cve
        };
        context.CvssData.Add(cvssData);
        var references = new References
        {
            url = "http://est.ch",
            source = "CVE@mitre.org",
            CVEDBModel = cve
        };

        context.References.Add(references);
        // Saves changes
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea where the problem is?

Kind regards
Stefan

Comment: Where is the database located?  The connection string is need a path where you can write the file : optionsBuilder.UseMySQL("server=localhost;database=cve;user=root;password=testr");

Comment: @jdweng The Database is Located on the host as I said, the tables are created, but not the entries

Comment: @StefanRöthlisberger I have fixed your bug and also submitted the proposal with name of Syed A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing your codebase you have defined a required check for the property `vulnStatus` for the class `CVEDBModel` defined inside the method `OnModelCreating` of class `OnModelCreating`

`entity.Property(e => e.vulnStatus).IsRequired();`

However when you are inserting the data you have not specified this value for the object due to which you are getting this error. But because you are just showing `Message` property from exception thus the error message was ambiguous.

You can improve this by writing an exception handler to handle validation error and show some meaningful error message.

Comment: I was so blind, that this was the issue.. Jesus, many many thanks

Comment: @StefanRöthlisberger It happens. But I guess I am still late for submitting proposal.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the error you're encountering is related to the entity configuration in your CVEContext class.

The ConfigureConventions method in your CVEContext class is adding a BlankTriggerAddingConvention to the model configuration builder. This convention may be causing the issue you're experiencing.

Try removing the ConfigureConventions method from your CVEContext class and see if that resolves the error. If it does not, you can try removing the HasTrigger method call in the ToTable configuration of the CVEDBModel entity.

If neither of these solutions work, please provide more information about the error message and where it is occurring in your code, as well as any relevant stack trace information.

Answer (score -1):

CvssData Class should include foreign key  of CVEDBModel to complete the relationship correctly, then you need to update your InsertData function to populate this value to CvssData.

Comment: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that you didn't define the relationships between the entities correctly in your OnModelCreating method. You need to properly define the foreign key relationships to make sure the data is saved correctly.

Here is how you should modify the OnModelCreating method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // ...

    modelBuilder.Entity<CvssData>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasKey(e => e.id);
        // ...
        entity.HasOne(e => e.CVEDBModel)
            .WithMany(e => e.CvssData)
            .HasForeignKey("CVEId"); // Replace "CVEId" with the name of the foreign key column you want to use
    });

    modelBuilder.Entity<Description>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasKey(e => e.id);
        // ...
        entity.HasOne(e => e.CVEDBModel)
            .WithMany(e => e.Description)
            .HasForeignKey("CVEId"); // Replace "CVEId" with the name of the foreign key column you want to use
    });

    modelBuilder.Entity<References>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasKey(e => e.id);
        // ...
        entity.HasOne(e => e.CVEDBModel)
            .WithMany(e => e.References)
            .HasForeignKey("CVEId"); // Replace "CVEId" with the name of the foreign key column you want to use
    });

    // ...
}
```

Make sure to replace "CVEId" with the name of the foreign key column you want to use in your database schema. Also, remove the line entity.HasOne(d => d.CVEDBModel).WithMany(p => p.References); from the References entity configuration, as it's already included in the updated configuration.

After making these changes, your program should work as expected and insert the data into the tables correctly.